# Trouble with C syntax

Tags: c

I'm currently implementing Bankers Algorithm in Linux C for a class. I'm used to c++, and am having trouble with some syntax in C. I've made a Job class, then a function that takes in the job class and assigns random numbers from 1-10 to them.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

struct job
{
    int requestA;
    int requestB;
    int requestC;
    int requestD;
    int requestE;
    int needA;
    int needB;
    int needC;
    int needD;
    int needE;
}

void process_rec(job *job1)
{
    int a_initial = 1 + (rand() % 10);
    int b_initial = 1 + (rand() % 10);
    int c_initial = 1 + (rand() % 10);
    int d_initial = 1 + (rand() % 10);
    int e_initial = 1 + (rand() % 10);

    int a_final = a_initial + (rand() %10);
    int b_final = b_initial + (rand() %10);
    int c_final = c_initial + (rand() %10);
    int d_final = d_initial + (rand() %10); 
    int e_final = e_initial + (rand() %10);

    job1.requestA = a_initial;
    job1.requestB = b_initial;
    job1.requestC = c_initial;
    job1.requestD = d_initial;
    job1.requestE = e_initial;

    job1.needA = a_final;
    job1.needB = b_final;
    job1.needC = c_final;
    job1.needD = d_final;
    job1.needE = e_final;


}
int main()
{

return 0;
}
```

I get the error, "Request for member 'RequestA' in something not a structure or union. Can someone help me out on what's wrong with my code? Also, how would I create one of my structs in my main function?

Comment: where is a call to process_rec() function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case

```
job *job1;
```

`job1` is a pointer. use the `->` operator.

Next, `job` is *not* a [primitive data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type).

Either you have to use `struct job`,

or, for better, change

```
struct job
{
    int requestA;
    int requestB;
    int requestC;
    int requestD;
    int requestE;
    int needA;
    int needB;
    int needC;
    int needD;
    int needE;
}
```

to

```
typedef struct job
{
    int requestA;
    int requestB;
    int requestC;
    int requestD;
    int requestE;
    int needA;
    int needB;
    int needC;
    int needD;
    int needE;
} job;
```

and you can use `job` as you have used in your code. However , both the cases, you need a `;` after the structure definition.

Note: It's always better to check for `NULL` before dereferencing a pointer, accepted as a parameter. Also, i'm assuming you're in the process of *updating* your `main()` function. :-)

Comment: I tried that and I still get the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code. In order to access the member of the structure you need to use `->` operator. We don't see you invoke your function and it needs to be done as shown in the code.
If you just want to use `job` instead of `struct job` you can do typedef `struct job job;`

```
struct job
{
    int requestA;
    int requestB;
    int requestC;
    int requestD;
    int requestE;
    int needA;
    int needB;
    int needC;
    int needD;
    int needE;
};

void process_rec(struct job *job1)
{
    int a_initial = 1 + (rand() % 10);
    int b_initial = 1 + (rand() % 10);
    int c_initial = 1 + (rand() % 10);
    int d_initial = 1 + (rand() % 10);
    int e_initial = 1 + (rand() % 10);

    int a_final = a_initial + (rand() %10);
    int b_final = b_initial + (rand() %10);
    int c_final = c_initial + (rand() %10);
    int d_final = d_initial + (rand() %10); 
    int e_final = e_initial + (rand() %10);

    job1->requestA = a_initial;
    job1->requestB = b_initial;
    job1->requestC = c_initial;
    job1->requestD = d_initial;
    job1->requestE = e_initial;

    job1->needA = a_final;
    job1->needB = b_final;
    job1->needC = c_final;
    job1->needD = d_final;
    job1->needE = e_final;


}
int main()
{
    struct job job;
    process_rec(&job);
    return 0;
}
```